# ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\Rpwebapps\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Rpwebapps\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.
```

onic:

Ionic CLI : 5.2.7 (C:\Users\Rpwebapps\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic) Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 4.8.1 @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3 @angular-devkit/schematics : 8.1.3 @angular/cli : 8.1.3 @ionic/angular-toolkit : 2.0.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1) Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0 Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 4 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.6.0 native-run : not installed

System:

NodeJS : v10.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe) npm : 6.4.1 OS : Windows 10

where i am missing, Environment Variables also created (paths) any one help me out

JAVA_HOME
JDK-location
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
GRADLE_USER_HOME
platform-tools
tools (Android\Sdk\tools) add variables

ionic cordova build android

Answer (score 8):

Yes, as it says you no longer can use ANDROID_HOME variable. You have to set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT instead.

1. Open control panel
2. Then go to System
3. Then go to Change Environment Variables of the User
4. Then click create a new environment variables
5. Create a new variable named ANDROID_SDK_HOME
6. Set its value to your Android directory
   C:\Users\Rpwebapps\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Comment: OR  You have to install Gradle, , if already install delete and reinstall then check now

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup environmental variable under "Path", just add your Android SDK path in that.
Along with it define each as below -

**Windows Env variables**

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT - location of your android SDK folder
ANDROID_HOME - location of your android SDK folder
JAVA_HOME - Location of your JDK folder
PATH - Locations where programs could be located
PATH Should Include
%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\emulator
%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\tools
%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\tools\bin
%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\platform-tools
%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\build-tools
%JAVA_HOME%\bin

C:\Program Files\nodejs
C:\Users<your username>\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

you can also refer to the video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQ498PINsws

Answer (score 1):

In case setting Environment variable is not resolving problem, 
you will need to install Gradle and set its environment variable.
Installing Gradle is very easy. You can get information at https://gradle.org/install/
Windows user, do this activity with cmd run as administrator. Mac/Linux user have to do sudo.

Always remember, After you do Environment variable settings as suggested above, Please start another cmd and try your required command there.

Answer (score 0):

In linux just change `ANDROID_HOME` to `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` in your `~/.bashrc`

where before was:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/{path}/android-sdk-linux"
```

now is:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/{path}/android-sdk-linux"
```

Don't forget source it: `$ . ~/.bashrc` after edition.

---

> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT:
> Sets the path to the SDK installation directory. Once set, the value
> does not typically change, and can be shared by multiple users on the
> same machine. ANDROID_HOME, which also points to the SDK installation
> directory, is **deprecated**.

ref: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables#envar

Comment: Note: Starting with Android Studio 4.2, the ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment variable is deprecated and has been replaced with ANDROID_PREFS_ROOT